My crochet blanket is kind of leaning to the left as it goes - almost like I somehow drop a stitch on the left and add one on the right?
I'm making a baby blanket and I'm about 110 rows in. It's 5 rows of half double crochet, then 5 rows of single crochet with baubles. It seems like the blanket is kinda leaning off the left - the half double crochet section leans left on both sides, like I side in the title almost like the right side is missing a stitch but the left has an additional one.
I've counted the stitches a dozen times and I'm pretty confident I haven't dropped or added any stitches. It seems like the issue is happening during the half double sections. Does anyone know what might be happening here?
The full blanket
Right side
Right Corner
Full album
Thanks for any help!

Your tension is slightly uneven and the many stitches amplify tiny differences into something visible.
I've copied the second-to-last section of half double crochet on top of the first section and connected every second stitch with a straight line:

The good news is that you can fix this to a certain degree by blocking the finished blanket. Blocking is the process of washing a knit or chrochet item, shaping it while wet (usually by pinning it into shape on a towel) and letting it dry in the desired shape. Here's a simple WikiHow.
However, if you continue crocheting like before, eventually the difference in size will be too much to be fixed by blocking. You should crochet the next few rows with deliberately firmer stitches (more tension on the yarn) to tighten up the sides and get back to your original size. Do it gradually over several rows to avoid sudden edges along the side.
